# Salesforce Flow missing closed parenthesis in formula

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm working on an email alert in flow trying to dynamically tell the user how many contacts were returned from the get query I did a step before. I've been staring at this for awhile and I can't seem to find where I am missing the ) that is preventing me from saving the flow. Can you help?

```
IF({!ContactCount} > 70, 
'Please note the number of contacts that have the old company account Billing Address as their Mailing Address is more than 70. Therefore, we've intentionally limited the report filter to the maximum Ids allowed to fit in the filter.', '') &
IF({!ContactCount} > 1 && {!ContactCount} <= 70, 
'Please note there are ' & {!ContactCount} & 'Contacts that have the old company account Billing Address as their Mailing Address. We've added those contact Ids into the report filter.', '') &
IF({!ContactCount} == 1,
'Please note there is 1 Contact that has the old company account Billing Address as their Mailing Address. We've added that contact Id to the report filter.', '')
```

Comment: As usual, indenting your formula as if it were code should pretty much always be the first step in debugging. That said, I'm not seeing anything obvious. I suppose the next step would be to try paring it down to a single IF() and then building it up until you get an error.

Comment: Your problem is `...we've...` - you wrapped the string with single quotes but the string has an embedded single quote. See [doc ref](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tips_for_using_text_formula_fields.htm&type=5) for solution

Answer (score 0):

Final Formula: it made me put everything to double quote and then I had to wrap the contactcount with text as it was a number.

```
IF({!ContactCount} > 70, 
 "Please note the number of contacts that have the old company account Billing Address as their Mailing Address is more than 70. Therefore, we've intentionally limited the report filter to the maximum Ids allowed to fit in the filter.",
 "") &
IF({!ContactCount} > 1 && {!ContactCount} <= 70, 
 "Please note there are " & TEXT({!ContactCount}) & " Contacts that have the old company account Billing Address as their Mailing Address. We've added those contact Ids into the report filter.",
 "") &
IF({!ContactCount} == 1,
 "Please note there is 1 Contact that has the old company account Billing Address as their Mailing Address. We've added that contact Id to the report filter.",
 "")
```